# How to install nibbler chess GUI

Tags: software-installation

I downloaded the [latest release](https://github.com/rooklift/nibbler/releases) of the [nibbler chess GUI](https://github.com/rooklift/nibbler) and i cannot find out what to do with the unzipped files.
Can anyone help me? There is no word of explanation on GitHub.
Do i need to install the unzipped files or just open it in some way?
Thank you very much for your help and your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest method is to set `nibbler` file to be executable and then run it by `./nibbler`.

If you want to install it to the system with desktop icon - use below commands

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget -c https://github.com/rooklift/nibbler/releases/download/v2.2.1/nibbler-2.2.1-linux.zip
sudo unzip nibbler-2.2.1-linux.zip -d /opt/
sudo chmod +x /opt/nibbler-2.2.1-linux/nibbler
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/share/applications

cat <<EOF | sudo tee /usr/local/share/applications/nibbler.desktop
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Version=1.0
Name=Nibbler
Icon=/opt/nibbler-2.2.1-linux/resources/app/pieces/K.png
Exec=/opt/nibbler-2.2.1-linux/nibbler
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=false
Categories=Game;BoardGame;
EOF
```

As the result you will find Nibbler in the desktop environment menu.

To call Nibbler from terminal you have to execute below command to create a symlink for it:

```
sudo ln -s /opt/nibbler-2.2.1-linux/nibbler /usr/local/bin/nibbler
```

and then call it using `nibbler` command.

---

You are free to report [issue to Nibbler developer](https://github.com/rooklift/nibbler/issues) about possible installer, snap/[flatpak](https://github.com/rooklift/nibbler/issues/169)/appimage/whatever package, [icon](https://github.com/rooklift/nibbler/issues/172) and so on.