# How to uninstall nibbler chess gui?

Tags: uninstall, chess

[How to install nibbler chess GUI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1372411/how-to-install-nibbler-chess-gui) as described here I installed nibbler chess gui but I want to remove it. how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

To remove Nibbler you have to rewind [the answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1372413/66509) as follows:

```
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/nibbler
sudo rm /usr/local/share/applications/nibbler.desktop
sudo rm -rf /opt/nibbler-*-linux
```

Comment: "rm: '/usr/local/bin/nibbler' silinemedi: Böyle bir dosya ya da dizin yok" gives a fault